# py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.toDF: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:

Tags: pyspark

Code:

```
from pyspark.sql.types import *
from pyspark.sql.functions import *

retail_sales_transaction = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="conform_main_mobconv",
    table_name="retail_sales_transaction"
).select_fields(["business week","transaction_key","dh_audit_record_type","dh_audit_active_record"])

#TODO: Implement delta logics here & exclude Deleted & Inactivve records here

  
df_retail_sales_transaction= (retail_sales_transaction.toDF().filter((f.col('dh_audit_record_type')!='DELETE') & (f.col('dh_audit_active_record')=='1')))
```

Error I'm getting is :

```
df_retail_sales_transaction= (retail_sales_transaction.toDF().filter((f.col('dh_audit_record_type')!='DELETE') & (f.col('dh_audit_active_record')=='1')))

py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o86.toDF.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 1 in stage 1.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 1.3 in stage 1.0 (TID 14, 172.35.203.73, executor 1): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
```

Comment: `retail_sales_transaction` is itself a `DataFrame` , there is no need to implicitly convert using `toDF`

Comment: Actually retail_sales_transaction is not a dataframe before. I'm converting it into the dataframe using .toDF ().

Comment: Can you add the entire stacktrace then

Comment: Notice that retail_sales_transaction is a [DynamicFrame](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-dynamic-frame.html?utm_source=pocket_mylist) not a DataFrame object.

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement something close to that, [Filter transform](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-transforms-filter.html) did the job. Try it:

```py
from awsglue.transforms import Filter

dynamicframeFiltered = Filter.apply(
    frame = retail_sales_transaction,
    f = lambda row: row["dh_audit_record_type"] != 'DELETE' and row["dh_audit_active_record"] == '1'
)
dynamicframeFiltered.toDF().show(1)
```